# Why is this iterator arithmetic not working?

Tags: c++, iterator

I am learning C++ for fun. I am trying to understand iterator arithmetic and have written a simple program that sums the first element in a vector with the last element. Next the second and second-to-last elements are summed. The process continues until all elements have been summed in this manner.

The issue seems to be with the `*(a.end() - 1 - it)`  portion of my code. If I remove  the `- it`, then I get the result I would expect. Adding the `- it` results in an error saying that

> there were build errors. Would you like to continue to run the last successful build?

The errors I receive from Visual Studio are as follows;

> E0075 Operand of `*` must be a pointer
>
> C2100 illegal indirection

I have already approached this problem in a different way and was able to accomplish my goal. My question is why is this code an error, and could it be modified slightly to execute properly?

I appreciate any advice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::cin;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::vector;

int main() 
{
    vector<int> a{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};

    for (auto it = a.begin(); it != a.begin() + (a.end() - a.begin()) / 2; ++it)
        cout << (*it) +  *(a.end() - 1 - it) << endl;

    return 0;
} // END MAIN
```

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8FkkY.png)

[Error list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tbwlQ.png)

Comment: `iterator - iterator` gives distance, not an iterator.

Comment: If you got a compiler error, why did you not include the exact error in this question?

Comment: Thanks for adding the errors, it's much better. Note that images are not easy for everyone to read unfortunately. Could you add the text of the error message to the question? Just the line "*indirection requires ...*" is fine. Having the images *additionally* is fine as well.

Comment: Thanks for adding the text, the question is quite nice now. I've edited it slightly to improve the formatting. There are other ways to do this of course, but this can give you some ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subtracting 2 iterators with `a.end() - 1 - it` gives you the distance between them. You can't dereference a distance with `*` and so you get a compiler error.

This distance from `a.begin()` to the element you want to get at is needed in the expression. You can adjust the expression slightly by just adding `a.begin()` to that distance:

```
 cout << (*it) +  *(a.end() - 1 - it + a.begin()) << endl;
                                 //  ^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/q4Gn3x).

---

From C++20, instead of dealing with iterators and manipulating them, you can deal with ranges directly, which can be easier to read once you get used to it:

```
// just for convenience
namespace sv = std::views;
namespace sr = std::ranges;

// size of half the range
auto half = a.size() / 2;
 
sr::transform(a | sv::take(half),                          // first half
              a | sv::reverse | sv::take(half),            // second half reversed
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, "\n"), // print out
              std::plus{});                                // the sum
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/nv3Ebb).

Comment: Thank you cigien. Your response was very helpful. I believe I understand where I went wrong in my thinking. Thanks again.

Comment: @AdamsK No problem. As mentioned in the comment on your question, you're missing the compiler error message. Please add that to the question to make the question more useful, and also compliant with the site rules.

Comment: @fabian Sure, there are various ways of making the code more readable. However, I would not make the claim of any version being more performant than the other without benchmarking, and profiling the code first.

Answer (score 0):

You should change code like this:

`auto fix = it - a.begin();`

`cout << (*it) +  *(a.end() - 1 - fix) << endl;`

you can't manipulate on iterators like integers, you just can simply add or sub integers or use starting point from begin() - as end() isn't a real pointer for some value in vector.